# I can't get the Allocation Callbacks from the VmaAllocator

Tags: vulkan

I want the `VkAllocationCallbacks` from VMA but there is no function, and when I try to get it through `m_AllocationCallbacks` or `GetAllocationCallbacks` I get an incomplete type error. VMA works with everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a fork of vma that added `vmaGetAllocatorAllocationCallbacks` and it works fine (https://github.com/NongusStudios/VulkanMemoryAllocator).